# Use your own colour for plots with guiqwt in python

Tags: python, plot

Is it possible to use your own colour (maybe specified by a hex-code) in the guiqwt module in python? 
I mean something like this:

```
my_colour = '#EE686B'

figure('my figure')
plot(x, y, '-', color = my_colour)
show()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I don't see the problem in your code. I don't know the guiqwt module but try using Matplotlib: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html

You can also try this color table:

```
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

  red   = QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0)
  green = QtGui.QColor(0, 200, 0)
  blue  = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 200)
  black = QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0)
  white = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255, 0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. But you are correct, in matplotlib this would work, but I would like to use guiqwt because of the nice matlab-like gui and also it is (usually) quite nice to handle.

Comment: Well, that is a way to define a colour but I don't know how to use this for a plot.

Comment: why don't you try this: plot(x, y, '-', color = QtGui.QColor(200, 0, 0)). See if it works and if it does just convert your color to this format.

Comment: So the problem is, the plot function has no attribute 'color'. So it does not work like this.

Comment: Then try with the `curve` function, instead of `plot`. Look at this example http://packages.python.org/guiqwt/examples.html?highlight=color

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-10, 10)
plt.plot(x, x**2, 'r+')
plt.show()
```